# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string[]>' to 'string[]'

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, casting

Below is my code which gives an error:
**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string[]'**

I tried several times to solve the error. But I failed to do so. 
if any body can suggest what could be the solution.. Thanks :)

```
public GetContentResponse GetContent(abcServiceClient client, QueryPresentationElementIDsResponse querypresentationelementresponse)
        {
            GetContentRequest GetContentRequest = new GetContentRequest();
            GetContentResponse contentresponse = new GetContentResponse();
            querypresentationelementresponse = presentationElementId(client);
            List<string[]> chunks = new List<string[]>();
            for (int i = 0; i < querypresentationelementresponse.IDs.Length; i += 25)
            {
                chunks.Add(querypresentationelementresponse.IDs.Skip(i).Take(25).ToArray());
                contentresponse = client.GetContent(new GetContentRequest()
                {
                    IDs = chunks // here i get this error
                });
            }

            return contentresponse;
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to assign a List to a string array. Convert the list to an array. 
Since you haven't specified exactly where the error was I suppose it's when you're assign the IDs variable.

The following code would solve it:

```
public GetContentResponse GetContent(abcServiceClient client, QueryPresentationElementIDsResponse querypresentationelementresponse)
        {
            GetContentRequest GetContentRequest = new GetContentRequest();
            GetContentResponse contentresponse = new GetContentResponse();
            querypresentationelementresponse = presentationElementId(client);
            List<string> chunks = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < querypresentationelementresponse.IDs.Length; i += 25)
            {
                chunks.AddRange(querypresentationelementresponse.IDs.Skip(i).Take(25));
                contentresponse = client.GetContent(new GetContentRequest()
                {
                    IDs = chunks.ToArray()
                });
            }

            return contentresponse;
        }
```

Comment: i also did the same thing.. but this did`nt helped me.
I can still try it again if you suggest to do so. :)
many thanks.

Comment: the error shown after doing as you said.
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[][]' to 'string[]'

Comment: I get this error where the IDs  = chunk is written.
Also have mentioned in the question as a commented line where specifically error arises.

Comment: Ah, now I see it, you actually have a list of string arrays. I changed my answer. You need to make just a list of string and add ranges to it

Comment: Kenneth, Your solutions works though.. builds fine but also need few modifications.. :)
anyways thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what type IDs is or what line is giving you that error, but if I had to guess, I think its `IDs = chunks`.

It sounds like you are trying to convert a list to a string array. You need to use a method to convert using toArray().

Edit: Ok, you have an array of string arrays. You need to grab the correct one with:

```
IDs = Chunks.ToArray()[index]
```

Where index is the correct array. Not terribly familiar with the libraries you are working with, so I unfortunately cannot elaborate. However, to take a wild guess, try using `i` in place of `index`.

Comment: Blast, Kenneth, you beat me to the submit button :P.

Comment: There's still opportunity, Chris. I'll bet `ID` is a `string[]`, and `chunks.ToArray()` will just return a `string[][]`.

Comment: But this solution is not helping though :p
Another try may give you win :D

Comment: @ChrisChambers, I already tried this, But this doesn`t even works fine with the scenario. :)
many thanks for the quick responses.. :)